# MySQL displaying value of comma separated string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get the value of comma separated string.

Ex string: apple, google, yahoo, stackover flow

code:

```
$arr=explode(",",$Tags);
foreach ($arr as $TagValue) {
    $ShowTags = strtolower($TagValue);
    echo '<ul class="tags">
    <li><a href="tags.php?tag='.$ShowTags.'">'.$TagValue.'</a></li>
    </ul>';
}
```

MySQL

```
$tag    = $_GET['tag'];

SELECT FROM posts WHERE active=1 and (tags LIKE '$tag%') ORDER BY id DESC
```

Issue is it is displaying 1st value (Ex: apple from the above mention) But none of the other values are getting displayed. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Can you please print_r($Tags) and tell me what is the results?

Comment: @KaushaMehta if string have the value apple, google, yahoo, stackover flow $Tags will display apple, google, yahoo, stackover without commas and as separated words

Comment: post an example in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I should add '%$tag%' instead of '$tag%'. This fixed the issue.